# After adding a column to a module's schema, should the new column also be placed inside hook_schema?

Tags: 6, database, installation, updating

I have my own module which implements its own schema. I now want to add a column to the table provided by the schema, which I plan on accomplishing via `hook_update_N()` and `db_add_field()`.

My question is essentially what the title of this question is: after I add the new column to the schema, should the new column **also** be placed inside the module's `hook_schema()` implementation? Example (adds a column named `mynewcolumn` to the schema of the module `mymodule`):

```
function mymodule_update_6000() {
  $ret = array();

  db_add_field($ret, 'mymodule', 'mynewcolumn', array(
    'description' => t('This is my new column'), 
    'type' => 'text',
    'size' => 'big',
    'not null' => FALSE
  ));

  return $ret;
}
```

At this point, do I place `mynewcolumn` inside `mymodule_schema()`? Or does `mymodule_update_6000()` fully take care of proper installation and uninstallation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_update_N()` is only used when updating a module, while `hook_schema()` and `hook_install()` are used only when installing a module. Since there are users who install the module, the database field must be also added in `hook_schema()`.